# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firebase.auth(...).getUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am having this code:

```
 firebase.auth().getUser(user.uid).delete().then(function() {

                console.log("user deleted");
              }).catch(function(error) {

                console.log("Error while deleting user " + user.email);
              });
```

Why do I get this error, if firebase.auth() is not null ?

And this is how I have included firebase:

```
 <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

For example, creating user in Authentication works for me, or updating real time database. But, when I try to delete user from Authentication, I get this error.

Comment: I don't really know about firebase but it feels wrong to do getUser() and chaining with delete since it's probably an async call

Comment: I have changed that to `var user = firebase.auth().getUser(user.uid); user.delete...` but I still get the same error. @Jordan

Comment: That's not really what i meant is it probably returns a promise so it would be something like this
 firebase.auth().getUser(user.uid)
    .then(function(user) {

      return user.delete();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('user deleted');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error while deleting user ");
    });
Also i checked the doc did you try this instead 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user
Sorry but like i said i dont really know it was just a feeling :x @Whirlwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), the Auth object returned by `firebase.auth()`.

Perhaps you are mixing it up with the [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth) object provided by the Admin SDK, which does not work in web browsers.  It has a [getUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUser) method, but that's not the SDK you're using.